# Uncaught reference error: quickread is not defined

Tags: javascript

I get an UncaughtReferenceError: QuickRead is not defined on line 10 which is `QuickRead.applyToLinks();`

I am using the script from here http://www.readshout.com/quickread and I believed I followed all the directions it has to use it, yet its not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.readshout.com/bookmarklets/quickread/quickread.js"></script>
        <script>
            //QuickRead.setFilter('a.my_links');
            QuickRead.applyToLinks();
        </script>
        <a href="http://robsheldon.com/giving-up-on-google">Give up on google</a><br />
        <a href="http://artchang.com/y-combinator-experience">ycomb exp</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me. You could however try to add jQuery 1.4.2 manually, as QuickRead seems to dynamically load it. Otherwise try Firebug to find the error.